# How to crop image programmatically (without views)

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crop

I have a bitmap, and I have a RectF with percentages for crop.

Something like x = 0.3, y = 0.1, height = 0.6, width = 0.7 for image with 100x100 px

means:
crop by X from 30 to 70 px, crop by Y from 10 to 60 px.

How can I do that crop without intents, cropping view and etc, I need just image cutted from original.

I found some kind of solution:

```
croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
```

but I am afraid of VERY big bitmaps, I need to crop original image, I cannot load it in sample size with downscaling

Comment: If you don't want to downscale images, try to use android:largeHeap="true" for application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: already using it, still some bitmaps can provide OutOfMemory, they could be up to 100mb in memory, not good

Comment: "they could be up to 100mb in memory" - I don't know of any Android device on the market that would be able to do that in one shot... You'd probably have to break the images into manageable sections and then figure out how to save them together, which would not be simple. Or, better, save only the augmentation data (e.g. scale, rotate, etc), and use it to render the changes at a downsampled level on your image as its needed. If the changes need to be rendered to a Gallery or something, you could send the augmentation data to a designated machine to handle the massive processing required.